# Attaching event to future iframe element

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to attach a click event handler to a element that will appear in the future. The element is in an iframe.

If it wasn't in an iframe I would use the following.

```
$(document).on('click', '#logout', function(e) {
    console.log('Click registered!')
}
```

For some reason my brain is failing me getting this to work for an element in an iframe (same domain).

Did a good search here but no-one that I can find with this exact issue.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event delegation depends on event bubbling, and events don't bubble out of the iframe into the parent document. So you have to bind the handler to the document within the iframe:

```
$("#iframe").contents().on('click', '#logout', function(e) {
    console.log('Click registered!')
}
```

Comment: Yes that looks like it'll work! So I'll mark it as correct... but I've just realised that in my situation the iframe isn't always present so I can't bind the handler to it. Silly me. I think I'll detect the iframe loading then bind the handler. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that's the best you can do, since nothing passes the iframe boundary.